# how I can call two api at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have two different API, one for comments for a video and one for the name of users, now I need to find names with the user id from comments API. I use this code.

```
function loadVideoCommentsById(id) {
        let output = '';
         fetch('https:///comments')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function (json) {
                json.forEach(function (comment) {
                    if (comment.videoId == id) {
                        const username =  fetch('/users/'+comment.userId)
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(function (json) {
                                return json.name;
                            });

                        output += `
                            <li>
                                <div class="Uid">
                                    <span>` + username + `</span> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="commentText">
                                    <p class="">${comment.body}</p>
                                    <span class="date sub-text">${comment.date}</span>

                                </div>
                            </li>
            `

                    }

                    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = output;

                })

            });


    }
```

when I put 'json.name' in alert, it prints the username but when I see on my website when I run it ' `+ username +` ':
it prints:[object Promise]
what should I do now? I am a beginner and it is the only way that I found for the username.
Thanks

Comment: you're failing to use promises correctly - of course username is a promise, that's what fetch returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you are doing

```
const username =  fetch ....
```

so, username will be a Promise, which is an object, which is why "it prints:[object Promise]"

Since you are dealing with multiple (async) requests inside the forEach, you'll probably need to use `Promise.all`

You'd also use .filter to filter for the "comments" you want, and .map to get an array of Promises for Promise.all to wait on

Here's code that should work

```
function loadVideoCommentsById(id) {
     return fetch('https:///comments')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => 
        Promise.all(
            // filter only the comments that match `id`
            json.filter(comment => comment.videoID == id)
            // get the username for each comment
            .map(comment => fetch('/users/'+comment.userId)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => ({username: json.name, comment}))
            )
        )
    )
    // data will be an array like [{username, comment}, {username, comment} ...]
    .then(data => data.map(({username, comment}) => `
        <li>
            <div class="Uid">
                <span>${username}</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="commentText">
                <p class="">${comment.body}</p>
                <span class="date sub-text">${comment.date}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        `
    ).join(''))
    .then(output => document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = output);
}
```

async/await version

```
async function loadVideoCommentsById(id) {
     let res = await fetch('https:///comments');
     let json = await res.json();
     let filtered = json.filter(comment => comment.videoID == id);
     let output = '';
     for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
         let comment = filtered[i];
         let res2 = await fetch('/users/'+comment.userId);
         let json2 = await res2.json();
         let username = json2.name;
         output += `
            <li>
                <div class="Uid">
                    <span>${username}</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class="">${comment.body}</p>
                    <span class="date sub-text">${comment.date}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        `;
     }
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: Is this the best practice for calling/merging two different API call? if not what is the best practice?

Comment: "best practice" is pretty opinionated - from the code you posted, what you *attempted*, this is how I would personally do it. One may use async/await, especially if the API for the username doesn't like multiple requests at once, but as that has not been mentioned anywhere, I declare this *my* **best practice**

Comment: How can I get the best practice? you said I can use async/await, do you have the solution or any source that explain the solution easily?

Comment: @makeupsite - added async/await version